# загрузка уже существующего файла в form symfony 3

Tags: symfony3

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой в симфони форм.
У меня уже файл существует, я хочу его поместить в форму (к примеру для редактирования профиля). Я сделал что-то типо такого:

```
    if ($Ups->getImage()){
         $d = new File($this->getParameter('brochures_directory').'/'.$Ups->getImage());

         $Ups->setImage($d);
    }

    [image:AppBundle\Entity\ToolBatteryUps:private] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File Object
    (
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/clients/client1/web72/web/app/../web/uploads/brochures/595cdb7e09e50.jpeg
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => 595cdb7e09e50.jpeg
    )
```

В итоге у меня в объект `$Ups` файл записывается, но в форме по прежнему

> Файл не выбран

в FormType.php:

```
->add('image', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Image plik', 'required'    => true))
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку, но тут как оказалось позже больше имелось ввиду о добавлении в форму элементов не с объекта. Что-то типо такого:
В formType

```
"mapped" => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

"Файл не выбран" - естественно, это же объект, а не путь на вашем компьютере.

Просто выведите текущее изображение на экран, а поле, где "Файл не выбран" используйте для обновления.

По этому поводу есть подробная [документация](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).

Единственное, что нужно изменить в `Entity` метод:

```
public function setBrochure($brochure)
{
    $this->brochure = $brochure;

    return $this;
}
```

на:

```
public function setBrochure($brochure)
{
    if($brochure!== null) {
        $this->brochure= $brochure;

        return $this;
    }
}
```